# Which GPIOs can receive DHT11 data?

Tags: gpio

The 'kookye' [DHT11 tutorial](http://kookye.com/2017/06/01/how-to-set-up-temperature-and-humidity-sensor-dht11-on-raspberry-pi-2/) suggests connecting to  GPIO14 (TXD) at pin 8.   An rpi3B+ and a [relay board](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CKwwwZAKDB5xXlpXwFOgv2Azo9jsXYtW) uses the GPIO14 for programming firmwware per the table:

```
PIN    GPIO   CLASS      RELAY BOARD FUNCTION 
3,5    2,3    SDA,SCL    I2C commands
7      4      GPCLK0     Interrupt Handler
8,10   14,15  TXD,RXD    Firmware Programming
```

The [Circuit basics tutorial](http://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-set-up-the-dht11-humidity-sensor-on-the-raspberry-pi/) indicates configuring GPIO-4 (GPCLK0) Pin-7:

[image]

## QUESTIONS

- Can a common GPIO (i.e. GPIO-17) be configured to receive DHT11 data?
- Which GPIOs can be configured to receive DHT11 data?

[image]

## TEST PROCEDURE

1. Enter this at the command prompt to download the library:

   git clone https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT.git
2. Change directories with:

   cd Adafruit_Python_DHT
3. Now enter this:

   sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
4. Then install the library with:

   sudo python setup.py install
5. Invoke python

   `sudo` python   # failure to sudo results in the execution failure below

and issue commands:

```
import sys; import Adafruit_DHT

humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 26) #GPIO-26 on pin-37
```

ERROR MESSAGES CAUSED BY NOT USING `sudo`: Retry with GPIO (26) and not PIN (37)

```
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 26)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 94, in read_retry
    humidity, temperature = read(sensor, pin, platform)
  File "Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 80, in read
    platform = get_platform()
  File "Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 55, in get_platform
    from . import Raspberry_Pi_2
  File "Adafruit_DHT/Raspberry_Pi_2.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import Raspberry_Pi_2_Driver as driver
ImportError: cannot import name Raspberry_Pi_2_Driver
```

UNUSUAL TEST RESULTS:

```
[19:28:24] openhabian@openhab:~/Adafruit_Python_DHT$ sudo ./examples/AdafruitDHT.py 11 26
Temp=7.0*  Humidity=55.0%
[19:28:47] openhabian@openhab:~/Adafruit_Python_DHT$ sudo ./examples/AdafruitDHT.py 11 26
Temp=7.0*  Humidity=55.0%
[19:29:13] openhabian@openhab:~/Adafruit_Python_DHT$ sudo ./examples/AdafruitDHT.py 11 26
Temp=7.0*  Humidity=56.0%
[19:29:21] openhabian@openhab:~/Adafruit_Python_DHT$ cd ..
[19:32:51] openhabian@openhab:~$ sudo ./Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/AdafruitDHT.py 11 26
Temp=3.0*  Humidity=**165.0%**
[19:33:02] openhabian@openhab:~$ sudo ./Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/AdafruitDHT.py 11 26
Temp=7.0*  Humidity=55.0%
```

Comment: (1)  YES, you can use GPIO17, if you won't consider using it for SPI1 later: https://imgur.com/PSwTXaK, (2) ALL Rpi GPIO pins can be used to receive DHT11 data, but actually you don't just use a GPIO pin toreceive data firom DHT11, if I remember correctly, the same GPIO pin is to send command signals to DHT11. But I forgot the details, perhaps I should search my old posts to refresh my memory. I tend to think that the I2C data pin might be a good choice, for the following reasons: (1) it have a strong pull up of 1k8. which means less noisy, longer distance, (2) ... forgot!, / to continue, ...

Comment: (3) Actually MCP23017 (or similar IOX devices) GPIO pins (more details later) is better, for a couple of reasons: (1) Newbie proof, because DHT11 kills the middle guy first, and if you see green smokes coming out, you can quickly pull the plug! :)

Comment: But Lada Ada says her old library your are using is depreciated, and suggests you to try her new CircuitPython library.

Comment: If you have a good tutorial link that you recommend to Adafruit's CircuitPython Libary, please consider posting it somewhere either as a comment or preferably as an answer.  I was able to read DHT11 sensor data with the procedure above in teh OP.  Thank you

Comment: I didn't catch you. Did you mean you can use the kookye tutorial python program to read DHT11, but no luck with the AdaFruit tutorial? BTW, even you find the Circuit Python library for DHT11, you cannot use directly with Rpi.  You still need to find another hacker to kindly convert the CircuitPython to Rpi python, because Rpi cannot install CP interpreter and run CP program smoothly. I did spend time in playing with MicroPython (MP), with PyBoard and BBC MicroBit and found is very compatible with CP (actually CP came from MP), and found it OK for newbies and small projects. A long story, :(

Comment: @tlfong01   Kookye python tutorial was successful.  I have not tried the Adafruit tutorial.  I think this [question might interest you](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/108330/40373)

Comment: Ha, your new question is indeed interesting, particularly the long wiring part. More about this later.  Coming back to CircuitPython. There are two python for newbie schools: (1) ESP8266/ESP32 microPython/NodeMCU LUA, (2) AdaFruit MicroPython and weak ARM core hardware, .. Ah lunch time.  See you later, ...PS - Before I go, something for you to read: MicroPython for EP8266 - 13. Temperature and Humidity
https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/tutorial/dht.html

Comment: My very long answer to your short DHT22 question: Rpi Forum Searched query: DHT22 tlfong01 - Search found 53 matches: DHT22 tlfong01
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/search.php?keywords=DHT22+tlfong01&sid=dd38af13df199c1b633e13f86b2c777b. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, I am telling my long story, about many things, including how I learnt I2C, in the writing style of "Stream of consciousness". Now my consciousness is diverting me to the following I2C stream: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1366025&hilit=DHT22+tlfong01&sid=9beea0531babbdb8bbe9480d22e96e54#p1366025. / to continue, ...

Comment: You seem to have imported the module incorrectly, perhaps as the root user which why it only appears to be visible to root.  On a properly set up Raspbian the Pi user is in groups i2c, spi, and gpio and no root privileges are required to access the GPIO.

Answer (score 1):

Any GPIO on the expansion header may be used to receive data from the DHT11 with the possible exception of GPIO 2 and 3 (pins 3 and 5).  GPIO 2 and 3 have 1k8 hard wired pull-ups to 3V3 which may interfere with the proper operation of the DHT11.

It would make sense to avoid GPIO which have specialised functionality like the I2C, SPI, and UART GPIO (as you may need those GPIO for another project later on).

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I was able to read temperature and humidity from the sensor.  Using sudo is required to invoke python for this exercise