# DHT22 long distance temperature measurements (24 meters wired)

Tags: dht22

**WARNING: Raspberry pi GPIO is designed for 3.3V: five volts will damage GPIO.**

A short 20cm cable and 3.3V powered a [successful DHT11 test](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108319/which-gpios-can-receive-dht11-data). I would like to reproduce this effort with 3 DHT22 sensors at distances of 20cm , 12m and 24m.

- Aosong marketing material indicates the [possibility of 20m](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0045/8932/files/DHT22.pdf?100745)
- [akaj9's forum entry #9: 5V Arduino forum indicates success at 60M](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=124368.0) with UTP wiring;  [image: diagram]

Goals include:

- measure temperatures at a distance from 12 and 24 meters from the rPi via DHT22
- wire (CAT5E) to power and receive data from two DHT22s per CAT5E cable to the rPi
- ensure the sensors are provided enough voltage, despite the voltage drop across the 12m and 24m CAT5E cable
- minimize (eliminate) the use of level converters (3.3v <=> 5.0V)

To clarify, two cables of 12 and 24 meters, each endpoint will have two temperature sensors.

I seek to avoid:

- damaging GPIO and stay by ensuring that it is not driven by greater than 3.3V

## QUESTIONS

DHT22 sensors are powered by 12m and 24m ethernet cables:

1. Will the sensors have enough voltage if powered at 5V?
2. Will the data voltage returned to the rPi be at a safe 3.3V?
3. If not, what can be done to ensure a safe 3.3V data return to the pi?
4. The calculations below show no voltage drops at 0.1 A   What (if any) flaws are in the calculation?

Any references to the topic or experience is appreciated.

## Voltage drop calculations

[CAT5 voltage drop calculations](http://www.netkrom.com/legado/voltage_loss_over_cat5_calculator.php):

25 meter with 2-twisted pair calculation:

[image]

12 meter with 1-twisted pair calculation:

[image]

## REFERENCES

[DHT11 DHT22 Electrical timing diagrams](https://www.electronicwings.com/sensors-modules/adxl335-accelerometer-module)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104419/discussion-on-question-by-gatorback-dht22-long-distance-temperature-measurements). Please cut out the anecdotes.

Answer (score 4):

Voltage drop due to wire resistance is usually a non-issue unless a significant current is involved. The factor that typically leads to issues first is the **capacitance** of your cable.

An [estimated capacitance](https://www.cirris.com/learning-center/calculators/174-cable-capacitance-calculator) of 10pF/feet for a twisted pair gives a value around 750pF for your longest cable. Together with the 10 kOhm pullup (inside the DHT11 sensor) the cable will effectively form a low-pass filter with a [characteristic frequency](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Low-pass-filter-calculator.php) of 21 kHz. The shortest pulse from DHT11 is about 25us, which will need at least 40 kHz of bandwidth to be reliably transmitted, so your cable is roughly two times too long.

You may be able to work around the issue by providing an additional external 10kOhm pullup, which DHT11 may just tolerate. This will drop the total pullup resistance to 5kOhm and increase the bandwidth, at the expense of bigger internal current in the sensor (which will likely affect precision).

Comment: Thanks for the analyzing the DHT11  I would appreciate your insight with similar DHT22 analysis.

Comment: The goal is to use the more accurate sensor: DHT22

Comment: @gatorback AFAIK there is no difference between the two as far as the digital signal is concerned. I have seen sites claiming that DHT22 already has a 5kOhm internal pullup, but I wouldn't trust any such value, considering if it can be trivially measured.

Comment: If the bandwidth is insufficient should I expect to see the majority of readings to fail or be obviously incorrect, or is the symptom insidious where it is difficult to detect (i.e. only one bit is flipped per reading).  I ask because I would like to understand how confident one can be when testing and reading seem good.  What is the longest DHT22 distance measurement in your projects?

Comment: DHT sensors send a checksum with every measurement, so I fail to see the difference between "reading obviously incorrect" and " one bit flipped". Both will have a wrong checksum. Personally would aim to have a good margin and not design the system to be on the edge of that's possible, and I would consider finding a sensor which actually supports long wires (e.g. current loop / CAN interface) or wireless operation, seeing how close to the limit you are with DHT.